# sqlite3 in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, sqlite

Is there any way to use sqlite3 with CI? I've previously used the sqlite3 pdo drivers, which had to manually be installed to the `/system/database/drivers` folder, but I was hoping there's another way to do it without altering the `/system` folder (which is generally a bad idea because you'll lose your changes when you update CI, which I'm going through right now)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  You can't implement a core change to a database driver.  There's no way around modifying /system.

Comment: There's no way to maybe extend the core loader class with a core class extension, changing it to check in somewhere like /application/database/drivers for db drivers?